# How do you configure rvmsudo using chef?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, chef, rvm

I am using the [chef-rvm cookbook](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm) by fnichol to perform a system wide installation of Ruby via RVM with the rvm::system recipe. I.e. In my run list, I have (with no additional attributes set):

```
recipe[rvm::system]
```

After I cook my ubuntu server, everything works fine as a regular user. i.e.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

However, rvmsudo doesn't seem to preserve the RVM environment, or correctly pass it on to sudo. I get the following error:

```
$ rvmsudo ruby -v
sudo: ruby: command not found
```

How do I use chef to configure my environment so that rvmsudo has access to the ruby / gem environment?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a problem with the current version of RVM itself (1.17.0), forcing an older version of RVM solves the issue. I did this by setting the following attributes:

```
node['rvm']['version'] = "1.16.13"
node['rvm']['branch'] = "none"
```

Answer (score 0):

You installed ruby only for your user. You should use rvm::system_install for system wide installation.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. From the documentation: This (recipe[rvm::system]) recipe includes default and system_install. So it would seem that I was already performing a system wide installation of RVM. system_install is used when I want to handle the installation of rubies myself. Not the case in this instance, happy to go with the default 1.9.3.